# How to restrict download a copy and print to read the PPT files in microsoft office online?

Tags: wordpress, iframe, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a powerpoint viewer on my worpress page that shows a ppt file. The problem is that I do not want to be able to download (i want read only), but I can not disable the Microsoft Office online options "download a copy" and "print pdf".

```
[embeddoc url="https://ceysformacion.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/CURSO-AMENAZA-DE-BOMBA.ppt" width="90%" height="90%" download="none" viewer="microsoft"]
```

I have also tried with css (display: none) on some classes, but without effect.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure about the possibility of disabling the MS online option for download so what I can see as a work around are:

> either change the way you render the ppt and do something like slide share or
>   add password/security protected on the file that can be downloaded.. well this is under the assumption that your purpose is to manage access on copies of specific files.

I also saw this thread, which may support my initial point that preventing download is still not available. But again, I am not entirely sure how accurate this info is. Hope it helps.

https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913531-onedrive-sharing-collaboration/suggestions/7105024-prevent-shared-files-from-being-downloaded

Comment: It's what I thought. The documents you share through Microsoft Office Online or Google Docs Viewer there is no way to prevent them from being downloaded. At least I can not find a way to do it. :(